# Terraform on Azure - Deploy multiple subnet

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

I'm trying to implement a Terraform script to create multiple subnets.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "test_subnet" {
    name = "testSUBNET"
    resource_group_name = "${local.resource_group_name}"
    virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.lab_vnet.name}"
    address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/24"
}
```

Is there a way to do a for-each or a loop on a variable in order to create them at the same time?

Comment: just replicate your azurerm_subnet resources?! You can have multiple of those in your terraform template. Or do I not understand your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes i know that i can duplicate it but the idea is to have a variable with subnets (it can be 1, 2, 3 ... depending on the need) and to automate it without changing the terraform script by hardcoding each time.

Comment: This blog post has actually a specific example for azure subnets: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/

Comment: What is the expected answer you want to get? I didn't see you accept anyone below.

Comment: @Makram hae provided an answer which i think covers your use cases :) let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using a variable and count index as follows:

```
variable "subnet_prefix" {
  type = "list"
  default = [
    {
      ip      = "10.0.1.0/24"
      name     = "subnet-1"
    },
    {
      ip      = "10.0.2.0/24"
      name     = "subnet-2"
    }
   ]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "test_subnet" {
    name = "${lookup(element(var.subnet_prefix, count.index), "name")}"
    count = "${length(var.subnet_prefix)}"
    resource_group_name = "${local.resource_group_name}"
    virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.lab_vnet.name}"
    address_prefix = "${lookup(element(var.subnet_prefix, count.index), "ip")}"
}
```

There is also preview feature available [for-each](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/) in the new version

Comment: Why do you have this as a map instead of a list?

Comment: Hello, with this script we will have the same name of subnet for both 10.0.1.0 and 10.0.2.0?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR you are right, the list seems to be better in this case. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Terraform 12 this can be achieved using the [for-each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) capability or the [count capability](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count)

**count** should be used if you are looking to create almost identical resources.

**for-each** should be used to create multiple of each instance based on a different map or set of values.

Using an list of strings and the `toset()` function to convert this is a neat way to achieve this

```
variable "subnet_ids" {
  type = list(string)
}

resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  for_each = toset(var.subnet_ids)

  ami           = "ami-a1b2c3d4"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = each.key # note: each.key and each.value are the same for a set

  tags = {
    Name = "Server ${each.key}"
  }
}
```

Or you could achieve this by using something like the below:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  for_each = {
    a_group = "eastus"
    another_group = "westus2"
  }
  name     = each.key
  location = each.value
}
```

If you are looking to achieve this with Terraform 11 the `count` and `variable` capabilities are the only way other than code duplication. (Rajat Arora has mentioned)

I would strongly recommended using Terraform 12 as the providers for Terraform 11 will be unsupported in the not to far future and if you can save yourself from refactoring now, you should!